# HTML anchor link for Google Lens

Tags: html, google-goggles

I'm developing a web application now, and I want to set to starting Google lens if the user click the icon in web browser on Android smartphone.

How can I code `<a href=""></a>` on html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I don't think that Google Lens offers an API for things like that.

You might want to take a look at Googles machine learning kit: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/